# Kendo Combobox - Advanced Filtering

Tags: kendo-combobox

Is it possible to filter on other properties in the datasource attached to a combobox?

For example, I have combobox with a list of customers, I want to be able to search on the customer name, First Name, Last Name and email.

Comment: Need to see what you have tried, what isn't working, etc...

Comment: The default filter works. meaning it searches the name because that is the field I have displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It is posible if you concatenate the fields you want to search in one.

ie: `concatField = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + email.`

You could show just the name if you want, but the textfield should be concatField.